# Only load lower media queries for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, media-queries, conditional-statements

I'd like to serve IE7 only the lower media queries (because I don't want to fix all the higher layouts), but I can't get conditional tags to work with this. Am I doing something wrong?

I've used respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), so it should be fine, but the conditional tags prevent all browsers from loading the higher media queries.

What should happen is that all browsers should load all media queries, whereas IE7 and downwards should only load my 601.css and 768.css stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.example.com/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/601.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 601px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/768.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 768px)"/>   

<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1024.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1024px)"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1280.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1280px)"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1600.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1600px)"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: just curious - what devices are you expecting to load your website under 600px in IE7? :)

Comment: It's more that IE7 messes up the layout when I get over 600px, so I want to stop it from doing that

Answer (score 0):

Right, got it. It seems that gt IE 7 only includes all IEs upwards. Instead we need to also include browsers that are NOT IE too.

so...

```
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1024.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1024px)"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1280.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1280px)"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mq/1600.css" type="text/css"  media="(min-width: 1600px)"/>
<![endif]-->
```